# existence of a positive root

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, polynomials

Consider the polynomial
$$
P(\omega)=\omega^8+\phi_7\omega^7+\phi_6\omega^6+\phi_5\omega^5+\phi_4\omega^4+\phi_3\omega^3+\phi_2\omega^2+\phi_1\omega+\phi_0
$$
with real coefficients. Assuming that $\phi_0>0$, I need to establish conditions under which $P(\omega)$ has at least one positive root. Ideas are welcome. Thanks.

Comment: Try using results from theory of equations. Here, "product of all the roots" is equal to $\phi_0$. So PoR $>0$

Comment: Perhaps you can some intuition by using Descartes's rule.[link](http://example.com)